# Two different HR of the same company contact me. What to do?

Tags: salary, applications

I was interested in working at a company that was offering two different positions. The positions were not the same but had some similarities. I was interested in both positions. In each advertisement they advised a different email address to apply.

Since I could not make up my mind and both looked good to me, I send the application and explained in the intro of my letter that I am interested in both applications and would be glad if I could apply for both. I set as recipients of the email both email addressed that were different and stated differently in both advertisements.

The next morning one of the HR persons of one of the positions contacted me and asked me which of the two positions I felt more identified with. I said actually both but if they require me to choose one, I chose one. The one I chose was the one that person was managing. So we moved forward to salary negotiation, etc.

In the middle of that screening the other HR person contacts me and tells me my application is really good and asks me about my salary expectation.

I am interested in both positions. What should I do?

Should I just move forward separately with the other HR person for the other position? Or should I tell her I withdraw my application since I am moving forward with the other application?

And now of course a crucial question is the salary expectation. Because I negotiated it already for the ongoing application, I have no margin (they do not have it either) to negotiate much.

Comment: You let them know you're interested in both jobs, and let them know each others' email addresses. You are not sneaky, and they can work it out between them. If both hiring managers want you, you will have to decide.  You can hardly go wrong telling HR   people you want to work for their company.

Answer (score 2):

Did anyone from the company warn you not to apply to more than one job? If yes, the you already made a choice.

Otherwise, it seems that they do not have a real problem with you applying for more than one job. I would honestly go to both interviews, and choose what is best at the end.

What they negotiate internally (IF they discuss anything internally) is not your concern.

> how to handle communication with the two recruiters at the same time

As if they were recruiters from different companies (in a way, they kind of are). You maintain two separated threads of discussion.

> Should I just move forward separately with the other HR person for the other position?

Yes, you should. If they have any internal rule, it is their responsibility to communicate it to you.

> Or should I tell her I withdraw my application since I am moving forward with the other application?

I would definitely not do that.

> And now of course a crucial question is the salary expectation. Because I negotiated it already for the ongoing application, I have no margin (they do not have it either) to negotiate much.

Different jobs have different salaries. Even in the same company. Your skills are more suitable for one of the jobs, so that job should pay better. But do not make this a blocking point. There is no rule that the "less suitable job" must not provide bigger salary. Maybe they are more pressed to have someone new in the team, even with less skills. It is a matter of negotiation.

---

Bottom line:

- two jobs;
- two different organizations in the same companies;
- two different recruiters;
- two threads of discussion;
- two negotiations;
- two (expected) salaries;
- maximum one job awarded in the end :)

(You might even get a better offer from another company and decline both of the current ones.)

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you might be excited/nervous/stressed out about this new oppertunity. Personally I would just keep going with the first position as you are already doing good (negotiating salary etc). Once you have a foot in the door I am sure it would be easier to move around in the company, if it turns out that is what you truly want.

Comment: You are right. Me question is about how to handle communication with the two recruiters at the same time.